# Search Engine in php?

Tags: php, logic, search-engine

I want to create a search engine in php (like Google, Ask). So, please tell me how can I create it. What is the logic for it?

Comment: Search engine for what? The world wide web?

Comment: seriously.  how can you expect a valid answer from such a broad and sweeping question.

Comment: Why not? That's not a stupid question.

Comment: if someone here could concisely tell you how to create the next google search engine i would be blown away.  an on top of that, why would they?  you're basically asking them to do all the work for you.  the 'logic' is build a web crawler, invest millions in server tech, create a web presence, and make lots of money...

Comment: I don't think it's such a bad question, but it would help you if you were more specific with your requirements. What do you want to search? A DB? A file? How do you want the search to output? How will your "users" use this feature? What are you building it for? If you can add this to your question I'm sure you'll get some answers and less negative points...

Comment: @Ganesh, agreed.  if he posed the question in a completely different way, it would be a valid question.  as it stands, i call shenanigans.

Comment: I just want to know how search engine is work

Comment: Maybe you should first learn how to use a search engine.

Comment: Ganesh is right, the way a search engine works varies entirely on its purpose.  something that searches a database works in a completely different way than something that searches files, which is completely different than what google does.  the basic idea though is, index the content you want to search, query the index, and then return the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are four basic functions that a search engine must perform:

1. Gather a list of websites to crawl.
2. Download the content of each of those web sites, and build up a mapping of "keywords" to pages.
3. Allow users to type in keywords and then match those keywords against the mapping you built in step #2.
4. Display the results from step #3 in a order that is relevant to the user.

It sounds simple, and if you have a small number of pages to search then it typically is. The difficulty comes from scaling from a 100s of pages to the billions of pages on the internet today.

Most of the difficulty - and what makes google better than many other engines - is not the technical ability to "search" billions of pages (that is, step 1-3), but deciding *which* of those billions of pages to show at (or near) the *top* of results (that's step #4).

For example, when you type "stack overflow" into google, there's 2.1 *million* pages in their index that matches those keywords: the thing that makes google good is it's algorithm for deciding that *this* stack overflow should appear as the first result (as opposed to say, the wikipedia article on the subject)

The way they do that is the subject of *many* university student dissertations, white papers, books and speculation. Rest assured the actual algorithm is a closely guarded secret at google and I doubt there's many who know the intimate details of every aspect of it. It's also something that's constantly changing.

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php
    echo '
    <form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get">
        <input type="textbox" name="q" id="q" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>';
?>
```

Comment: haha, this answer should have been accepted!

Comment: @Tiois, I thought it was the best answer to the question... ;)